# Code duplication for just an if condition

Tags: java, design-patterns, depth-first-search

I have two methods that are near-perfect duplicates. There is of course a code smell. The only thing that changes is the condition to increment a variable.

Language: Java7

```
private int pathsDFS(int currentDepth, int maxDepth, Airports s, Airports e, Predicate predicate) {
    int counter = 0;
    if (currentDepth > maxDepth) return counter;
    int newDepth = currentDepth + 1;
    for (Edge x : g.getNeighboursOf(s)) {
        if ( x.getDestination() == e) {
            counter++;
        }
        counter += pathsDFS(newDepth, maxDepth, x.getDestination(), e, predicate);

    }
    return counter;
}
```

and

```
private int pathsDFSB(int currentDepth, int maxDepth, Airports s, Airports e) {
    int counter = 0;
    if (currentDepth > maxDepth) return counter;
    int newDepth = currentDepth+1;
    for (Edge x : g.getNeighboursOf(s)) {
        if (x.getDestination() == e && currentDepth == maxDepth) {
            counter++;
        }
        counter += pathsDFSB(newDepth, maxDepth, x.getDestination(), e);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

What pattern can I apply to remove duplication? I was trying to apply like a Predicate class (calling apply) but that doesn't solve the fact the the values to use are known at runtime inside the for method. Could be considered a strategy pattern the entire for loop?

Comment: These methods are in the same class or in different classes?

Comment: Also is there a reason for the `predicate` in the first method? It is not doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a parameter `boolean incrementOnAnyDepth` and in your if condition write

```
if ( x.getDestination() == e && (incrementOnAnyDepth || currentDepth == maxDepth) )
{
    counter++;
}`
```

Comment: That's a good idea. But what about the different recursive calls? If there is no reason for the `predicate` then making a single method instead of two and your answer can solve it.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly the aim was to make one method out of the two - and the predicate was just a try... because it's not used anywhere in the code

Comment: Yes the predicated was a try.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to separate the traversal from the processing logic.

Define an interface

```
interface IEdgeVisitor {
    boolean done(int depth);
    void visit(Edge edge, int depth);
}
```

Define visitors implementing the interface, e.g.

```
class EdgeVisitor : IEdgeVisitor {
    private int counter;
    private int maxDepth;
    private Airport airport;

    public EdgeVisitor(int maxDepth, Airport airport) {
        this.counter = 0;
        this.maxDepth = maxDepth;
        this.airport = airport;
    }

    public boolean done(int depth) {
        return depth > this.maxDepth;
    }

    public void visit(Edge edge, int depth) {
        if (edge.getDestination() == this.airport && depth == this.maxDepth) {
            this.counter++;
        }
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return this.counter;
    }
}
```

And pass in the visitor as a parameter

```
private void dfs(int depth, Airport start, Airport end, IEdgeVisitor visitor) {
    if (visitor.done(depth)) {
        return;
    }
    int newDepth = depth + 1;
    for (Edge edge : g.getNeighboursOf(start)) {
        visitor.visit(edge, depth);
        dfs(newDepth, edge.getDestination(), end, visitor);
    }
}
```

(Disclaimer: my Java is rusty, this is not tested.)